# Powershell returning System.Object[] instead of information due to multiple results

Tags: powershell

Ive a script that emails information of login to us.

I am calling username like this : 
`$username = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'" | ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() } | Select-Object -Unique -Expand User`

The reason i am doing this as someone helped me to avoid the username from task manager and call the real users that are logged in instead of the account the task is running under.

The issue I am having is as there are multiple users logged in I am getting System.Object[] returned to me instead of the actually results.

Here is an example of my code :

```
$IP = Get-NetTCPConnection -state ESTABLISHED -Localport 3389 | Select -ExpandProperty RemoteAddress
$username = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'" | ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() } | Select-Object -Unique -Expand User
```

Then I just call these in my body as so :

```
$message = "`nUsername :",$username ,....etc
$body = $message
```

Would anyone know why this would be returning System.Object[]?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The powershell syntax "abc","def" is the same as @("abc","def") both of which returns a string array.
You could use one of these syntaxes instead:

```
$message = "`nUsername : $username"
$message = "`nUsername : " + $username
```

In case you get several user names (maybe "$usernames" would be more suitable), just use something like

```
$message = "`nUsernames : " + $usernames -join ", "
```

In case you don't know if you get 1 or more usernames, you might want to use this instead:

```
$username = @(Get-WmiObject [...] -Expand User)
```